# Update aspnet membership password answer

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, hash, asp.net-membership

I am going to update security question and answer in aspnet_Membership. Usually it is done by code:

```
 user.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer(password, question, answer);
```

But I don't know the password. I found that there is a default stored procedure.The stored procedure is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[aspnet_Membership_ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer]
    @ApplicationName       nvarchar(256),
    @UserName              nvarchar(256),
    @NewPasswordQuestion   nvarchar(256),
    @NewPasswordAnswer     nvarchar(128)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @UserId uniqueidentifier
   SELECT  @UserId = NULL
   SELECT  @UserId = u.UserId
   FROM    dbo.aspnet_Membership m, dbo.aspnet_Users u, dbo.aspnet_Applications a
   WHERE   LoweredUserName = LOWER(@UserName) AND
        u.ApplicationId = a.ApplicationId  AND
        LOWER(@ApplicationName) = a.LoweredApplicationName AND
        u.UserId = m.UserId
   IF (@UserId IS NULL)
   BEGIN
      RETURN(1)
   END

   UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Membership
     SET    PasswordQuestion = @NewPasswordQuestion, PasswordAnswer = @NewPasswordAnswer
    WHERE  UserId=@UserId
   RETURN(0)
   END
```

However I just found the answer is a clear text. How can I use the stored procedure and hashing it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't actually quite understand the question, but it looks like you're asking if it's possible to hash answers ? If that's the case, you might want to have a look at `HASHBYTES`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

Comment: The reflected ASP.NET way: http://forums.asp.net/t/1338984.aspx/1

Comment: @Tim, it reqiured password but I suppose the admin guy doesn't know the user's password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to the user you can change their password prior using the Membership method:

```
public virtual bool ChangePassword(string oldPassword, string newPassword)
```

You could try

```
string newPassword = user.ResetPassword();
user.ChangePassword(newPassword, "SOMENEWPASSWORD");
```

Then do

```
user.ChangePasswordQuestionAndAnswer("SOMENEWPASSWORD", question, answer);
```

Comment: The hard part is we have to reset the user's password. But the user maybe not want to do it. I want to avoid it.

Comment: Are the user passwords stored as Hashed?

Comment: I guess so. In web.config: <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" connectionStringName="DB" minRequiredPasswordLength="8" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" applicationName="db" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>

Comment: If they are hashed its going to be difficult without knowing their password.  Is it an option to just let the user create and update their security questions and answers, along with resetting their own password?

Comment: Is YS' method HASHBYTES okay? I tried it, but it doesn't match with SHA1 hash method.